# Multi-threading with TPL - Access Internal Class Properties

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am using the TPL library to parallelize a 2D grid operation.  I have extracted a simple example from my actual code to illustrate what I am doing.  I am getting the desired results I want and my computation times are sped up by the number of processors on my laptop (12).

I would love to get some advice or opinions on my code as far as how my properties are declared.  Again, it works as expected, but wonder if the design could be better.  Thank you in advance.

My simplified code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Gridding
{


    public abstract class Base
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Values representing the mesh values where each node in the gridis assigned som value. 
        /// </summary>
        public float[,] Values { get; set; }
        public abstract void Compute();
    }


    public class Derived : Base
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Make the mesh readonly.  Is this necessary?
        /// </summary>
        readonly Mesh MyMesh;

        Derived(Mesh mesh)
        {
            MyMesh = mesh;
        }


        public override void Compute()
        {
            Values = new float[MyMesh.NX, MyMesh.NY];

            double[] xn = MyMesh.GetXNodes();
            double[] yn = MyMesh.GetYNodes();

            /// Paralellize the threads along the columns of the grid using the Task Paralllel Library (TPL).
            Parallel.For(0, MyMesh.NX, i =>
            {
                Run(i, xn, yn);
            });
        }


        private void Run(int i, double[] xn, double[] yn)
        {
            /// Some long operation that parallelizes along the columns of a mesh/grid
            double x = xn[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < MyMesh.NY; j++)
            {

                /// Again, longer operation here
                double y = yn[j];

                double someValue = Math.Sqrt(x * y); 
                Values[i, j] = (float)someValue;
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int nx = 100;
            int ny = 120;
            double x0 = 0.0;
            double y0 = 0.0;
            double width = 100;
            double height = 120;

            Mesh mesh = new Mesh(nx, ny, x0, y0, width, height);

            Base tplTest = new Derived(mesh);
            tplTest.Compute();

            float[,] values = tplTest.Values;

            Console.Read();


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// A simple North-South oriented grid.
        /// </summary>
        class Mesh
        {
            public int NX { get; } = 100;
            public int NY { get; set; } = 150;
            public double XOrigin { get; set; } = 0.0;
            public double YOrigin { get; set; } = 0.0;
            public double Width { get; set; } = 100.0;
            public double Height { get; set; } = 150.0;
            public double DX { get; }
            public double DY { get; }

            public Mesh(int nx, int ny, double xOrigin, double yOrigin, double width, double height)
            {
                NX = nx;
                NY = ny;
                XOrigin = xOrigin;
                YOrigin = yOrigin;
                Width = width;
                Height = height;
                DX = Width / (NX - 1);
                DY = Height / (NY - 1);
            }

            public double[] GetYNodes()
            {
                double[] yNodeLocs = new double[NY];
                for (int i = 0; i < NY; i++)
                {
                    yNodeLocs[i] = YOrigin + i * DY;
                }
                return yNodeLocs;
            }

            public double[] GetXNodes()
            {
                double[] xNodeLocs = new double[NX];
                for (int i = 0; i < NX; i++)
                {
                    xNodeLocs[i] = XOrigin + i * DX;
                }
                return xNodeLocs;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're simply looking for advice on code structure and/or quality then [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is probably the more appropriate site for this question.

Comment: Thank you, I will.

Answer (score 0):

With only 100 to 150 array elements, parallelism setup overhead would offset the gains. You could cache the result  of `GetXNodes()` and `GetYNodes()` and invalidate the cached values when XOrigin, NX, YOrigin or  NY are modified.